# How can I create string while writing file?

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I have a webservice. When I call the function webservice create a file in my pc. I want to create a string from file contents while file is creating.

My function is :

```
OutStream report = new FleOutStream("report.txt");
request.setReportOutputStream(report);
invokeGetReport(service, request);
```

after this function report.txt was created. I write this class

```
public class OutStr extends FileOutputStream
{
....
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("b");
        super.write(b, off, len); 
    }
....
}
```

and change my object to

```
OutStr report = new OutStr("report.txt");
```

I see many b in console. But how can I get text ?

Comment: You'll probably want to build a new String out of the bytes you're writing. Take a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this variable inside your class:

```
private String myString = "";
```

replace "System.out.println("b");" with this:

```
myString = new String(b, off, len);
```

then obtain the value with a getter

```
public String getMyString()
{
    return myString;
}
```